# Japanese currency formatting for readability

Tags: php, currency, cjk, money-format

I'd like to format Japanese currency into the standard "quickly readable" format.

Basically, all amounts over 10,000 yen are written using the character "万" (pronounced "man").

More on "万"
http://www.romajidesu.com/kanji/%E4%B8%87

So, 1,000,000 yen would simply be 100万 or "one hundred man". That's roughly $1,000 USD.

*Virtually no one in Japan would ever say "one million yen". The currency is always broken into 10,000 yen bundles.*

Consequently, when you buy a car, the sticker on the windshield says (e.g.) "140万"

So, I'd like to display that format. However, number_format, I believe, does not allow for defining the separation at 10,000, and money_format is likewise unhelpful.

Any thoughts on a best practice method for accomplishing this?

In summary:

- 10,000 yen should read 1万
- 100,000 yen should read 10万
- 1,000,000 yen should read 100万

Comment: Take amount on blur and divide by 10000. apply number format later

Comment: This will be a solved problem, but you may have to be literate in Japanese to find it. Someone over there will have created a library to do this because all of their websites will have to have done this too.

Comment: Do you want to go into using 億 as well…?

Comment: No, I'm only dealing with amounts up to about 1 million yen

Answer (score 0):

I have ever written that in my [WordPress plugin](https://ja.wordpress.org/plugins/auto-currency-converter/),

```
/**
 * convert number expressions to value
 *
 * @assert ("34000") == "3万4000円"
 * @assert ("123456.789") == "12万3457円"
 * @assert ("1234567890") == "12億3456万7890円"
 * @assert ("92610000000000") == "92兆6100億円"
 */
public static function formatInJapanese($value) {
    $isApproximate = false;
    $formatted = '';
    if ($value > 1000000000000) {
        if ($value % 1000000000000 !== 0) {
            $isApproximate = true;
        }
        $unitValue = floor($value / 1000000000000);
        $formatted .= $unitValue . '兆';
        $value -= $unitValue * 1000000000000;
    }
    if ($value > 100000000) {
        if ($value % 100000000 !== 0
            && !$isApproximate) {
            $isApproximate = true;
        }
        $unitValue = floor($value / 100000000);
        $formatted .= $unitValue . '億';
        $value -= $unitValue * 100000000;
    }
    if ($value > 10000) {
        if ($value % 10000 !== 0
            && !$isApproximate) {
            $isApproximate = true;
        }
        $unitValue = floor($value / 10000);
        $formatted .= $unitValue . '万';
        $value -= $unitValue * 10000;
    }
    if ($value != 0) {
        $formatted .= round($value);
    }
    return $formatted . '円';
}
```

It only works with man, oku and cho.

Quick search gives me that Ruby gem [number_to_yen](https://github.com/ttanimichi/number_to_yen) doing similar.

Comment: You might want to look at that Ruby gem a bit more. Emulating that could cut this function down to about a third of its size.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with is similar to the above.

```
function format_yen_for_display($yenAmount)
{
    /*
        Converts Japanese currency to easily readable local format

        10,000 yen should read 1万
        100,000 yen should read 10万
        1,000,000 yen should read 100万
        1,259,000 yen should read 125万 9,000円
    */

    if($yenAmount > 10000)
    {
        //amount over 1万
        $manYen = floor($yenAmount/10000);

        //amount under 1万
        $remainderYen = ($yenAmount - ($manYen * 10000));

        //concat
        $returnNum = "<span class=\"ylarge\">" . $manYen . "万</span>";

        //if remainder is more than zero, show it
        if($remainderYen > 0)
        {
            //format remainder with thousands separator
            $remainderYen = number_format($remainderYen);

            $returnNum .= "<span class=\"ysmall\">" . $remainderYen ."円</span>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $returnNum = "<span class=\"ylarge\">" . $yenAmount . "円</span>";
    }
    return $returnNum;
}
```